# Installing Festival 2.4 on Windows 7 using Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gnu-make, windows-7-x64, festival

I am trying to install Festival 2.4 on my Windows 7 64-bit using Cygwin 2.5.1. I tested the C++ compiler and it worked. But as I started to install speech tools (which must be installed first), I encountered an error when calling make.

```
$ make
../config/config:197: ../config/systems/x86_64_unknown.mak: No such file or directory
```

The problem (I think): after running configure, the system expects to find the following file: "x86_64_unknown.mak" but in my folder, I only have (among others): "ix86_CYGWIN20.1.mak", "ix86_CYGWIN32.mak", "ix86_CYGWIN324.0.mak", and "unknown_unknown.mak". Are there other mak-files for Festival, or how can I create the correct ones? This is really the first time for me installing programmes using Make and using cygwin, and I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

From [the README](https://github.com/usc-isi-i2/festival-text-to-speech-service/blob/master/README.md)

> Installation Instructions for Festival
>   Requirements
>
> Unix-based environment, preferably Linux (Do NOT use Windows with Cygwin)